# Parsing Json in PHP openweatherAPI

Tags: php, json, parsing

```
{
    "message": "accurate",
    "cod": "200",
    "count": 1,
    "list": [
        {
            "id": 2347078,
            "name": "Birim",
            "coord": {
                "lon": 9.997027,
                "lat": 10.062094
            },
            "main": {
                "temp": 307.488,
                "temp_min": 307.488,
                "temp_max": 307.488,
                "pressure": 968.5,
                "sea_level": 1022.03,
                "grnd_level": 968.5,
                "humidity": 61
            },
            "dt": 1402666090,
            "wind": {
                "speed": 1.41,
                "deg": 263.501
            },
            "sys": {
                "country": ""
            },
            "clouds": {
                "all": 0
            },
            "weather": [
                {
                    "id": 800,
                    "main": "Clear",
                    "description": "Sky is     Clear",
                    "icon": "01d"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Parsing this in php i am able to get id name and lon and lat but i cant get the icon...
how to get the icon?
my code is:

```
$lat = $_REQUEST['lat'];
$lng = $_REQUEST['lng'];
$response = file_get_contents("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/find?lat=$lat&lon=$lng&cnt=10");

$response = json_decode($response, true);
$t = $response['list'];
foreach ($t as $s) {
    $w = $s['weather']
    foreach ($w as $k) {
        $url="http://openweathermap.org/img/w/"+$k['icon'];
    }
    <img src="<?php echo $url?>" /></p>
```

**SOLUTION:**

The solution was that i used the + instead of the . as pointed out in the comments

```
  `$url="http://openweathermap.org/img/w/".$k['icon'];`
```

Comment: $lf=$k['icon'];
            $url="http://openweathermap.org/img/w/$lf.png";

ok got it .. seems i had it right just wasnt putting the $url properly .. silly me :/

Comment: Your problem was the `+$k['icon']`. The `+` symbol is used for JavaScript concatenation, you should have used the PHP `.` instead

Comment: use `.` for concatenation. if the structure is always going to be the same. you could just access it directly `$t['list'][0]['weather'][0]['icon'];`